# Failed to log into Docker mongo db

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

What's weird is this is identical to what I've done in other microservices, so I am confused.

So here's my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '4.12.0'

services:

  mongo:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo:4.4.16
    environment:
      MODE: SINGLE
      MONGO_USER: mongoadmin
      MONGO_PASS: mongoadmin1234
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

and my application.properties

```
# MongoDB Config
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongoadmin:mongadmin1234@localhost:27017
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.database=database-demo
```

when i go to start up spring boot i'm getting an authentication failed:

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'Authentication failed.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Authentication failed.", "code": 18, "codeName": "AuthenticationFailed"}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:175) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:358) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:279) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslStart(SaslAuthenticator.java:227) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.getNextSaslResponse(SaslAuthenticator.java:134) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar:na]
```

Additionally, with mongo DB compass, i can't log in with that user/pass either. This connection string works:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017
```

But this doesn't.

```
mongodb://mongoadmin:mongoadmin1234@localhost:27017
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace MONGO_USER with **MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME** and MONGO_PASS with **MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD**

Comment: your solution fixed not being able to connect directly w/ mongo DB compass. it didn't fix that spring boot is unable to connect.

Comment: where is your sprint boot application running? on the host or in a different container?